# spring security in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using spring security in grails and need authenticate (a) customer in my Customer class and I don't want use Role class or such a thing just want use authentication and annotation.
My customer just log in and with the log in must be authenticated.
Any body have done that ?
How I can write my own provider calss for authentication a customer?
I need some code to see how it's working

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Security Core plugin has to be the single best documented plugin available for Grails. Check out Peter's tutorials [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/). The two videos and code samples on that page should be more than enough to get you going.

If after watching Peter's videos you are still not satisfied take a look at the official Spring Security Core docs [here](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#6%20Helper%20Classes). Section 5.4 covers what you want to know.

In short, if you want to use annotations in each controller and don't care about the user's role then the following code will make sure they are logged in. Placing this at the top of the controller you are worried about will make it so all actions in that controller require a user to be logged in.

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
```